# Convolution between eigenfunctions of the Laplacian on $L^2(\mathbb{T}^3)$?

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

Let $L^2(\mathbb{T}^3)$ be the L^2 space on $3$-dimensional torus. That is, I am considering periodic functions.

Then, it is well-known that the there exists a smooth orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{T}^3)$ consisting of eigenfunctions of the Laplacian $-\Delta$.

Let us denote such an eigenbasis by $\{f_n\}$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_n$.

Now, let us suppose that $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$ and consider the convolution $f_1 * f_2$, which is clearly smooth and periodic on $\mathbb{T}^3$.

But my observation is that,
\begin{equation}
-\Delta (f_1 * f_2)=(-\Delta f_1) * f_2 =f_1 *(-\Delta f_2)
\end{equation}
so that, $(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2)f_1 * f_2 =0$.

However, I already assumed that $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$. Thus, $f_1 * f_2=0$.

Is my reasoning correct? That is, convolution of eigenvectors for $-\Delta$ corresponding to different eigenvalues is just identically zero?

Comment: These eigenfunctions are explicit, they are complex exponentials and you can directly prove that their convolution is zero unless $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$.

Comment: I don't know why you take $\mathbb T^3$ (seems like a useless complication to me); on $\mathbb T^1$ you have that $e^{in\cdot}\ast e^{im\cdot}(x)=0$ if $n\ne m$. The same happens in higher dimension